# Backup solution for hosted server.

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, backup, cloud

We have a need to backup around 6GB's worth of .bak files on a weekly basis. These files are stored on a hosted dedicated server running Windows Server 2008 r2. Unfortunately the constraints on this solution mean it has to come at zero cost.

I have looked at SkyDrive and with their 25GB limit it seemed like the perfect solution, but the maximum upload size of 100MB proved to be a stumbling block.

I have mapped SkyDrive to our hosted server as a network drive and currently transferring the batch of .bak files across but I'm expecting it to bomb out before competition. Unless the 100MB limit is specific to the web interface only?

Has anyone made use of a solution to a similar problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

4 sites that give you 10gb of storage:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-best-sites-10gb-free-online-storage/
I suggest that if backups are that important to you- you pay for a solution -- Does your hosting provider offer something?